# Ionic ios failed build

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have problem when i bulid ios using ionic cordova build ios --release

how can i solve it , i am using macOS

```
 Apple-User:alfraseh FirasHunaiti$ ionic cordova build ios --release
    > ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform ios
    Error: spawn EACCES

        at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:313:11)
        at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:503:9)
        at spawn 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:17:18)
        at spawn 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:124:12)
        at ShellCommand.spawn 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:113:16)
        at ShellCommand.run 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:80:24)
        at Shell.<anonymous> 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/shell.js:32:37)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:107:75
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Try with sudo : `sudo ionic cordova build ios --release`, I already had this problem because of permissions issues in the project files

Answer (score 0):

Build the project for ios (Xcode) `sudo ionic cordova prepare iOS` or `sudo ionic Cordova build ios` then go to the platform folder in the project and open with xcode the one that I export to you, and from xcode compile the project.